# Different ways to call an extension method in c#

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Hi I have a simple enum Service on which there are few extension methods defined

```
public enum Service
{
   //enum values ..
}

public static class ServiceExtensions
{
   internal static string GetSomeCode(this Service service)
   {
      // Does something
   }

   //another extension method that calls GetSomeCode()
   internal static string GetSomeOtherData(this Service service)
   {
      // Look at the call for extension method here
      string code = GetSomeCode(service);
   }
}
```

I know that the syntax for calling extension method is similar as calling for member function for `this`  specified type.

In above example it should be as -

```
string code = service.GetSomeCode();
```

I found similar use of syntax at other places in the project. I my question is there any difference between both the calls. If not then which should I prefer using ?

Comment: No there is not. The latter one is just a syntactic sugar it will be translated to the former.

Comment: prefer the one _you prefer_ - but if you're going for the static call, there's not really a point in making it an _extension_ method

Comment: The code will ultimately produce the same stack call and output. Choose whatever syntax you want but stay consistent within your whole application and call it with the same syntax everywhere for better readability

Comment: I would assume it was clearer for the developer that the `= GetSomeCode(service)` expression was clearer that it went to a different method in the same class than `service.GetSomeCode()`. I do the same thing myself. I use the extension method syntax outside of the class declaring the extension method, and if I need to call other methods inside the same class I use the normal method call syntax. This, however, is just an opinion. Both types of statements will compile to the exact same output.

Comment: There is a slight difference in that `GetSomeCode(service)` allow you to specify a namespace. As far as I know there is no way to do that with the `service.GetSomeCode()` syntax.

Comment: I think the point of `Extensions` is, to call the method like a native member ("Extend" the original type). When you prefer to call it like a method, you just need a static method (w/o `this` for the first argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no difference. Further more the latter (`service.GetSomeCode()`) will be converted to the former (`GetSomeCode(service)`) during compilation.

If you visit [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/) and paste there the following code:

```
public enum Service
{
}

public static class ServiceExtensions
{
   internal static string GetSomeCode(this Service service)
   {
       return "";
   }

   internal static string GetSomeOtherData(this Service service)
   {
      
      string code = service.GetSomeCode();
      return code;
   }
}
```

Then you will see that the decompiled code will look like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: Extension]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
public enum Service
{

}
[Extension]
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    [Extension]
    internal static string GetSomeCode(Service service)
    {
        return "";
    }

    [Extension]
    internal static string GetSomeOtherData(Service service)
    {
        return GetSomeCode(service);
    }
}
```

So, it is just a syntactic sugar.